# blending array-data using colormaps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three 2D-arrays with data that I would like to combine into one image
using three different colormaps. My current approach does not work:

1. normalise the array
2. apply a colormap turning each element/pixel into an array of 4 (RGBA)
3. average the three resulting arrays as a blending mechanism and
4. present the result

The result is not an image with four colored areas but something I do not understand. I cut my code down to something that hopefully shows the problem.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**:

A serious typo messed up the result (ax.imshow(res[0],...  instead of ax.imshow(res,... ). The result is now what I expected.

The blending problem is solved by Emilien, giving the "right way" to obtain the minimum values.

The upper-right corner is "yellowish", probably requiring to create my own colormaps that have real white on one side.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def normalise(v):
    m=np.amax(v)
    if m==0:
       return v
    return v/m

# three arrays
myarray0 = [[2,2],[0,0]]
y0 = normalise(myarray0)
myarray1 = [[3,0],[6,0]]
y1 = normalise(myarray1)
myarray2 = [[0,0],[8,0]]
y2 = normalise(myarray2)

# mapping
cmap0 = cm.RdPu
m0 = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap0)
im0 = m0.to_rgba(y0)
cmap1 = cm.PuBu
m1 = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap1)
im1 = m1.to_rgba(y1)
cmap2 = cm.YlGn
m2 = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap2)
im2 = m2.to_rgba(y2)

# blending
# res=(np.array(im0) + np.array(im1) + np.array(im2)) / 3
# getting the minimum, as suggested by Emilien:
res = reduce(np.minimum, [np.array(im0), np.array(im1), np.array(im2)])

# showing
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(res, interpolation='bilinear',
          origin='lower', extent=[0,3,0,3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you need to use three colormaps? Would it be simpler to blend the data instead of the resulting colors? According to your comment, maybe something like this could do: `res = reduce(np.minimum, [np.array(im0), np.array(im1), np.array(im2)])` but I don't really get what you try to achieve. Which is the same than if you change the `+` by commas in the commented out expression.

Comment: I use three colormaps because they represent three different streams in a 2D space. I want to show how the three streams are separated (and sometimes merge/split).

Comment: The suggestion to use `res = reduce(np.minimum, [np.array(im0), np.array(im1), np.array(im2)])` to blend the images gives a very nice result. Thank you!